# Apply special tags to textarea in all selected text even if there are newline capturing all contents in cursor poisition

Tags: javascript, string, tags, textarea, newline

The example below writes tag [code] and [/code] to selected text in textarea but only applied to begin and at the end of the string... I'd like to have [code] and [/code]
applied to every part of the strings considerating newline as new string...

example posted performs:

```
[code]test
test
test[/code]
```

I'd like to apply instead:

```
blablabla...
[code]test[/code]
[code]miao miao[/code]
[code]this is teh 3rd string[/code] 
etcetera, some extra string
```

as you can see I'd like to apply code only selected string considerating a new string with newline... it's possible in pure javascript? No jquery or mootools, please only standalone script...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
  <title>[javascript code]</title>
  <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    var myValueBefore = "[code]";
    var myValueAfter = "[/code]";
    function applyCode(myField, myValueBefore, myValueAfter) {
      if (document.selection) {
        myField.focus();
        document.selection.createRange().text = myValueBefore + document.selection.createRange().text + myValueAfter;
      } else if (myField.selectionStart || myField.selectionStart == '0') {
        var startPos = myField.selectionStart;
        var endPos = myField.selectionEnd;
        myField.value = myField.value.substring(0, startPos)+ myValueBefore+ myField.value.substring(startPos, endPos)+ myValueAfter+ myField.value.substring(endPos, myField.value.length);
      } 
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>

<br><br><br>
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="15" cellspacing="0" width="70%">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <form action="#" method="post">
      <input type="button" value="Apply Code" onclick="javascript:applyCode(test, myValueBefore, myValueAfter);"><br>
      <textarea rows="5" cols="130" name="test"></textarea>
      </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can develope this codesnippet further:

```
var myValueBefore = '[code]',
    myValueAfter = '[/code]';
function applyCode(myField, myValueBefore, myValueAfter) {
    var newLine = new RegExp('\n|\r\n', 'g'), range, selectedText, beforeSelectedText, afterSelectedText;
    if (document.selection) {
        range = document.selection.createRange();
        range.text = myValueBefore + range.text.replace(newLine, myValueAfter + '\n' + myValueBefore) + myValueAfter;
        return;
    } else {
        beforeSelectedText = myField.value.substring(0, myField.selectionStart);
        afterSelectedText = myField.value.substr(myField.selectionEnd);
        selectedText = myField.value.substring(myField.selectionStart, myField.selectionEnd);
        myField.value = beforeSelectedText + myValueBefore + selectedText.replace(newLine, myValueAfter + '\n' + myValueBefore) + myValueAfter + afterSelectedText;
    }
    return;
}
```

[A live demo at jsFddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bRxRW/1/).

Comment: I'm experiencing a problem under IE8, under IE8 there are two newline instead of one, how to fix IE?

Comment: @user1582059 I'm sorry, I can't reproduce this problem, though I can only emulate IE8 with IE10. You could try `'\r\n'` as a RegExp argument.

Comment: I'm wrong... the problem is IE... is not very important version since I tried on Windows 7 with IE 10.00 and the problem is still here... so how can I fix IE issue? IE adds two newline instead of one... and this is not worderful...

Comment: @user1582059 Now I got it :). Looks like IE uses `\r\n` in the `textarea` too. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for fixing IE issue :)